# Retrieving multiple JSON objects in C#

Tags: c#, php, json, pdo

I have a simple button that runs a script to pull data from 40 tables, within the php these are encoded in JSON.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT* FROM form");
$stmt->execute();
$results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$form=$results;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicant");
$stmt->execute();
$results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$applicant=$results;


print json_encode(array($form,$applicant));
```

I am not using select * it is just for easy reading. this displays fine as an array , however when im pulling the array into C# this is done as a string, how do i pass an array from php to c#?

```
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var json = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/returnData.php");
            List<Applicant> app = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applicant>>(json);
            List <form> form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<form>>(json);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = form;
            dataGrid2.ItemsSource = app;
```

*Idea 1*
This could be bad practise but could i run a script for each table and then just return each JSON object individually, i know this will work but will this be performance heavy and will have to create multiple scripts.

```
[{"id":"1","name_id":"0","first":"advert","last":"","address":"","postcode":"2","date_created":"2016-08-09 15:50:12"},{"id":"2","name_id":"0","first":"advert","last":"","address":"","postcode":"2","date_created":"2016-08-09 16:25:04"}]
```

*Idea 2*
i could create one script but return all with a separator. for example `print $form."^".$app;` then split them into an array in C#?

*Idea 3*
i would ideally like to pass the array of json arrays to c#.

Answer (score 2):

That `wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/returnData.php")` code line will try and download the entire resource `returnData.php` which will not only include the printed JSON array but as well that page HTML markup and thus your deserialization to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applicant>>(json)` logically should fail.

You should rather try and get those data directly from your C# code (OR) expose those method as Web API method (I mean REST service) and call them from your C# code to get the required data.

Comment: the php has no HTML markup, but could you point me in the right direction for a REST service as i do not want to call the data in C# just for security reasons.

Comment: also my JSON return with out a key, could i separate the values using a key?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var json`?

Comment: please see question

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

Please create a class like this
   //Jsonget.cs

```
public static string jsonconvert(string url)
{
string currentsite = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
wc.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
string test = "http://" + currentsite + url;
var data = wc.DownloadString(test);
string jsonresult = "{\"results\":" + data.ToString() + "}";
return jsonresult;
}

string jsonurl = "";
string getjsonresult = "";

getjsonresult = Jsonget.jsonconvert("http://localhost/returnData.php");
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Result= Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(getjsonresult);


foreach (var get_result in Result["results"])
{
string id= (string)get_result ["id"];
string name_id= (string)get_result ["name_id"];
}
```